# Python Glob doesn't recognize file pattern with arbitary numbers 2 to 12 in a path string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to get an `OR` condition inside the file path for glob to recognize it? something like `source_path = path + ('[1-9]+'|'[1-9][0-1]+')`, mainly to recognize file with filename as (just an exaample):

```
filename_2, 
filename_3, 
filename_10, 
filename_11,
```

```
import glob 
source_path = path + '[1-11]*'
for file in gb.glob(source_path): 
    print('file=', file) #'--gives no output

source_path = path + '[1-9]*'
for file in glob.glob(source_path):
    print('file=', file)
```

This code only detects `filename_2` and `filename_3`.

Comment: ``[1-11]`` won't work, you should use ``[1-9]|1[0-1]`` instead.

Comment: You're using regular expression patterns here, which are entirely unrelated to glob patterns.  The range 2-12 is simply not expressible via glob.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Python Glob doesn't recognize file pattern with arbitary numbers 2 to 12 in a path string" Yes; neither glob nor regex is an appropriate tool for this, and neither works the way you expect. You should start by reading the documentation. These tools don't parse numbers out of the data; they simply work on characters in the string. `[1-11]` means "symbols that are between `1` and `1` inclusive on the Unicode chart, or the `1` symbol". That is - just `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Number of items to match the file name : `01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11` something like this works:

```
0[1-9]|1[0-1]
```

For more information read this [.regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html)